# dynamic_reconfigure with programatically filled enum?

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ROS gurus. I want to ask you for your opinions to a topic I recently thought about.

I'm writing a ROS&Python driver for a series of web cameras. There is a lot of variability in the specific models, including supported image resolutions.

Now I want to offer a dynamic_reconfigure interface for setting (not only) video resolution. My basic thought was to filter a list of possible resolutions somehow to only publish the supported resolutions on `parameter_descriptions` (thus displaying only them in `rqt_reconfigure`).

But then I found out that even the set of possible resolutions is not bound and new resolutions may emerge with new camera models.

I have 2 ideas on what to do with that:

- alter `dynamic_reconfigure` and create another `edit_method` (that's lot of work, though)
- create my own implementation of `dynamic_reconfigure.Server`, which would read the allowed resolutions from somewhere and would publish the corresponding `parameter_descriptions`. In the `cfg` file I would probably create a dummy one-element enum in order not to stop existing tools from working.

I'm only concerned about this solution working from `dynamic_reconfigure` CLI, `rqt_reconfigure` and Python (ideally using the standard `Client`). I don't (yet) care about C++ clients.

Before I start working, could you please give me some feedback on how you like these ideas and what possible shortcomings do you see?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220443/dynamic_reconfigure-with-programatically-filled-enum?/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found an even easier way: directly changing the `config_description` attribute of the dynamic reconfigurable type before creating the server. The server then reads the changed enum description and correctly advertises the desired set of possible values.

I'm not sure about how it works with C++ clients, but both `rqt_reconfigure` and `dynparam` CLI work without problems for getting and setting parameter values. And since `dynparam` is a Python script, I assume the Python client has also no problems.

Here's a simple implementation (not considering parameter groups): https://gist.github.com/peci1/912549b79fd6e8801023

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0